# Accessing spring configured HashMap from applicationContext inside any classes in the Project

Tags: java, spring

Trying to create (Key,Value) pair i.e., HashMap in the applicationContext and trying access it from a class through @Resource annotation.

But it is unable to inject hashMap and getting null in the @Resource variable.

**ApplicationContext :**

```
<bean id="explicitWaitTime" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="COSCO" value="15"/>
            <entry key="Hamburg" value="15"/>
         </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**Business Class :**

```
public class BusinessClass implements IBusinessClass {    

@Resource 
private Map<String, String> explicitWaitTime;

@Override 
public void getExplicitWaitMaps() {  // From IBusinessClass interface

System.out.println("ExplicitWaitTime " +     
explicitWaitTime.get("COSCO"); //explicitWaitTime is null

}    
}
```

Comment: Can you use `@autowired` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to inject:

- In your application context file, define another bean for your business class and using constructor or setter injection, inject a hashmap. For this, you will have to provide either parameterized constructor or a property setter depending upon if it can work with or without hashmap.
- use Auto wired annotation

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `BusinessClass` class with @Component and let spring container instantiate it.